# LED and Switch Compolation Error Arduino 101

Tags: programming, c++, led, switch

I'm getting an error on line 9 for some reason, (digitalWrite(Sender, HIGH);), and I just cant figure out why. My goal is to have two sets of flashing patterns, one for each switch state. I don't know how important this is but I'm using an Arduino 101. This is also my first day programming so the answer could be staring me right in the nose, (in fact, I would prefer that haha). Thank you for your time!

```
// Starting this by declairing intigers
int Sender = 2; // Switch Out on pin two
int LedG = 10; // LED Green out on pin ten
int LedR = 11; // LED Red out on pin eleven
int Reader = 12;  // Switch Input on pin twelve
//configuring I/O
pinMode(Sender = OUTPUT); // Setting pin two to output 
pinMode(Reader = INPUT); // Making pin 12 set to read switch data
digitalWrite(Sender, HIGH); //Making pin two hot
//main loop
void loop() {
  if (digitalRead (Reader) == HIGH) { // if Switch input is reading on than do pattern A
    digitalWrite(LedG, HIGH); //turning on green led
    delay(50); //delay next instruction
    digitalWrite(LedG, LOW); //turn green led off
    digitalWrite(LedR, HIGH); //turn red led on
    delay(50); //delay next instruction
    digitalWrite(LedR, LOW); //turn red led off
  }
  else { //if switch input is readion off than play pattern b
    digitalWrite(LedR, HIGH); //turn red led on
    delay(1000); //delay next instruction
    digitalWrite(LedR, LOW); //turn red led off
    digitalWrite(LedG, HIGH); //turning on green led
    delay(1000); //delay next instruction
    digitalWrite(LedG, LOW); //turn green led off
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice that your pinMode function calls are not quite correct:

```
pinMode(Sender = OUTPUT); // Setting pin two to output 
pinMode(Reader = INPUT); // Making pin 12 set to read switch data
```

Should be:

```
pinMode(Sender, OUTPUT); // Setting pin two to output 
pinMode(Reader, INPUT); // Making pin 12 set to read switch data
```

Refer to https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PinMode for more information.

And the whole section where you configure your I/O should be wrapped inside the `setup()` function.

```
//configuring I/O
void setup()
{
    pinMode(Sender, OUTPUT); // Setting pin two to output 
    pinMode(Reader, INPUT); // Making pin 12 set to read switch data
    digitalWrite(Sender, HIGH); //Making pin two hot
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, my if statement doesn't seem to be functioning correctly.  Is (if (digitalRead (Reader) == HIGH)) the correct way to check if an input is true?

Comment: Never mind, sorry.